# Javascript: access to an object's member by name

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `themesData`:

```
var themesData = {}
themesData.a = { key: "value" }; 
themesData.b = { key: "another value"};
```

...and I want to access one of the members by its name. I get a string which contains either "a" or "b" and I want to get the appropriate member's value.

I'd be happy to get some help on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`themesData["a"].key` does what you need and is equivalent to `themesData.a.key`, still the "array index style" notation allows you to dynamically generate index names.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in this way:

```
var member="a"; //or B
var rightMember=themesData[member].key;
```